# PowerBI - Filter by Value

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I have a table with different phone numbers. Each number has its own opening time. Is there any possibility to display the numbers filtered by the opening times?

Comment: you want a filter on Now(), yes, this is possible

Comment: I have several Lines with DateTime Values (like 14.06.2021 15:07:34). if a number is for example 3383 the filter has to be until 4.0 pm, on other numbers until 6pm

Comment: Add some sample data and your desired result. Currently for me is unclear what you need.

Comment: Table 1
https://pastebin.com/QSf0ag75

Table 2
https://pastebin.com/8xWbY9A8

So from Table 1 "b_GroupDataGUID" is in Table 2 "GUID"
In PowerBI only data should be displayed that lie within the times from table 2.